# How to know which package yum is going to download or install now? 

Tags: fedora, centos, yum, redhat-enterprise-linux, netstat

Now I am installing a couple of packages using yum on centos, what make me confused is that the system seems to be block at some point, in fact I know yum is downloading some packages from repo, but I am not sure which package it is download now

I know yum is in fact a python script, so I use command to find what python is doing on my system now

```
pgrep python -lf
4406 /usr/bin/python -tt /usr/sbin/yum-updatesd
4903 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/yum -y install php-mbstring php-mysql which gcc-c++ php-imap php-pear php-devel lxlighttpd httpd mod_ssl zip unzip lxphp lxzend mysql mysql-server curl autoconf automake libtool bogofilter gcc cpp openssl pure-ftpd yum-protectbase
5130 /usr/bin/python -tt /usr/bin/puplet
```

I am sure it is downloading something now

```
----tcp-sockets---- -net/total- ----total-cpu-usage---- ------memory-usage-----
lis act syn tim clo| recv  send|usr sys idl wai hiq siq| used  buff  cach  free
  4   4   0   0   2|  22k 2364B|  0   0  99   0   0   1| 154M   39M  492M  326M
  4   4   0   0   2|  21k 1354B|  0   0  97   0   0   2| 154M   39M  492M  326M
  4   4   0   0   2|  19k 1342B|  0   0  99   0   0   1| 154M   39M  492M  326M
  4   4   0   0   2|  11k  988B|  1   1  97   0   0   1| 154M   39M  492M  325M
  4   4   0   0   2|  19k 1162B|  0   0  99   0   0   1| 154M   39M  492M  325M
  4   4   0   0   2|  19k 1312B|  0   0  99   0   0   1| 154M   39M  492M  325M
```

So the fact is I can find yum is going to download a list of files, but still don't know what file it is downloading now?  So is there any method which I can use to figure out which file yum is downloading now?  Or which file it is installing now?

Answer (score 2):

If I am not misunderstanding the question.. The verbose -v switch should be all you need.

```
sudo yum -v install package
```

Comment: but that yum is invoked in a set of scripts, it's difficult to change all yum to be yum -v, so can i use alis yum='yum -v' here？

Comment: @hugemeow: set `debuglevel` in `/etc/yum.conf`